# C programing: How to pop last element on linked list?

Tags: c, linked-list

I am beginner programer and one week ago i was introduced to linked list however I'm still struggling to wrap my head around this.

Currently trying to write a function that will help me remove last element from the linked list. I would appreciate some explanation what am i doing wrong here. Thank You for any suggestions.

I'm not allowed to touch or modify current structs

Here is my structs:

```
typedef struct node {
    ElemType val;
    struct node *next;
} NODE;

struct list_struct {
    NODE *front;
    NODE *back;
};
```

And heres my current code:

if list is empty, we do nothing and return arbitrary value
otherwise, the last element in the list is removed and its
value is returned.

```
ElemType lst_pop_back(LIST *l) {


    NODE * p = l->front;
    NODE * trail = l->front;


    if( p == NULL) return 0;

    if( lst_len(l) == 1){
        free(p);
        l->front = NULL;
        l->back = NULL;
    }
    else{
        p=p->next;

        while( p != NULL){

            if( p->next == NULL) free(p);

            trail = trail->next;
            p=p->next;
        }
        trail= trail->next;
        trail->next= NULL;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'm using Xcode on MAC and the error that i get is: Thread 1: EXC_ACCESS(code=1, address=0x8)

Comment: *I would appreciate some explanation what am i doing wrong here.* - why do you think you're doing something wrong? Are you being presented with errors/segfault/unexpected output?

Comment: Ok, so you changed the heading re doubly linked list. So now I go back to my original "off topic" comment: What is the point of the `back` member in `list_struct` if you only have a singly linked list.

Comment: You also seem to do something wrong when you construct the singly linked list. So please add that part of your source code.

Comment: the struct is given by a professor  that we aren't allowed to touch... Project consists 16 function where 11 we have to implement ourselves. He provides names of the function and parameters and the rest we have to do ourselves

Answer (score 0):

The XCode error `EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0x8)` means that somebody tries to access unaccessable memory. XCode's boundary checks are said to be good, so let's trust them. It is a bit sad that the OP doesn't tell us the exact line-number but one can guess. I would concur with Katerina B. here and assume the same lines as the culprit.

In detail:

```
ElemType lst_pop_back(LIST * l)
{
  // p and trail point to the first node
  NODE *p = l->front;
  NODE *trail = l->front;

  if (p == NULL)
    return 0;

  if (lst_len(l) == 1) {
    free(p);
    l->front = NULL;
    l->back = NULL;
  } else {
    p = p->next;
    // Now: trail->next points to the old p
    // and p to p->next, that is: trail points
    // to the node before p

    // while trail is not the last node
    while (p != NULL) {
      // if p is the last node
      if (p->next == NULL){
        // release memory of p, p points to nowhere from now on
        free(p);
      }
      // Following comments assume that p got free()'d at this point

      // because trail points to the node before p
      // trail->next points to the node p pointed to
      // before but p got just free()'d
      trail = trail->next;
      // p got free()'d so p->next is not defined
      p = p->next;
    }
    // assuming p got free()'d than trail->next is one step
    // further into unknown, pardon, undefined territory
    trail = trail->next;
    trail->next = NULL;

  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the error you're getting happens when you try to access something that's already been deallocated. You're doing that here:

```
if( p->next == NULL) free(p);

trail = trail->next;
p=p->next;
```

Since the list structure contains a back pointer, I'd recommend using that to help you. Maybe let `p` move through the list until `p->next` points to the same thing as the list's back pointer, then make `p->next` null.

Also, should the function POP or REMOVE from the list? Your question says removing but the function is named lst_pop_back. If you're poping, you'll need to return the last value too.

Comment: What makes you think that that would be a double free?

Comment: pop removes and returns. I think the OP got that part clear even though he fails to implement anything useable you can see the return type is `ElemType` which seems to be a typedef to int.